# ESP32 BLE and Android phone(s) - presence detection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, sniffer

**Is there a possibility how to "overcome" BLE MAC address randomization and detect presence of my own Android phone(s)?**

I'm looking for a solution how to detect presence of my phone in close-range to ESP32 without installing something like iBeacon app which would drain my battery.

- I've started with example for BLE sniffer which works nice but with MAC randomization on Android it is useless.
- Then I moved to the solution using emulation of a HID keyboard. After pairing it, it is nicely reconnecting when the phone comes into the range. Once it is connected I can trigger needed action and then I can turn ESP32 Bluetooth off not to be connected whole time. When I need check the phone again I just can turn the server back on. It would be neat solution but... I need to check more (at least two) phones. I've tried to duplicate BLEServers to swith between or run two simoutinasly but without success - either it is not possible or it is exceeding my knowladge about this BLE advertising/pairing/connecting magic.
- Third solution would be to have separate ESP for each phone - doable but only as a last resort

**Has somebody solved such task somehow already?**

For the keyboard solution I'm using this code found online:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include "BLE2902.h"
#include "BLEHIDDevice.h"
#include "HIDTypes.h"
#include "HIDKeyboardTypes.h"
#include <driver/adc.h>

BLEHIDDevice* hid;
BLECharacteristic* input;
BLECharacteristic* output;
BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising;
BLEServer *pServer;

bool connected = false;
bool restart = false;

class MyCallbacks : public BLEServerCallbacks {
  void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer){
    connected = true;
    Serial.println("Connected");
    BLE2902* desc = (BLE2902*)input->getDescriptorByUUID(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2902));
    desc->setNotifications(true);
    // NEEDED ACTIONS
  }

  void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer){
    connected = false;
    Serial.println("DisConnected");
    BLE2902* desc = (BLE2902*)input->getDescriptorByUUID(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2902));
    desc->setNotifications(false);
    restart = true;
  }
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting BLE work!");
  BLEDevice::init("Backpack-MeowMeow");
  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());
  pServer->getPeerDevices(true);

  hid = new BLEHIDDevice(pServer);
  input = hid->inputReport(1); // <-- input REPORTID from report map
  output = hid->outputReport(1); // <-- output REPORTID from report map

  std::string name = "ElectronicCats";
  hid->manufacturer()->setValue(name);

  hid->pnp(0x02, 0xe502, 0xa111, 0x0210);
  hid->hidInfo(0x00,0x02);

  BLESecurity *pSecurity = new BLESecurity();
  //  pSecurity->setKeySize();
    pSecurity->setAuthenticationMode(ESP_LE_AUTH_BOND);

    hid->startServices();

    pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
    pAdvertising->setAppearance(HID_BARCODE);
    pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(hid->hidService()->getUUID());
    pAdvertising->start();
    hid->setBatteryLevel(7);

    //ESP_LOGD(LOG_TAG, "Advertising started!");
    //delay(portMAX_DELAY);
}

void loop() {
  
  if(connected){
    delay(10);
  }
  if (restart) {
    restart = false;
    pAdvertising->start();
  }
  delay(50);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to track all android phones around you or just a specific set you have control of?

Comment: Just a specific ones. Therefore pairing is not a problem.I started with sniffing first because I don't want to install apps which would drain battery but it seems it is not a possible way.

Comment: Another problem with sniffing: Not every android phone is advertising via BLE and you will find only devices that are advertising.

Comment: BLE can be very power efficient if you regulate the advertising interval. Depending on your use case you could advertise only every 10 seconds or even less. This slows down detection on your esp32 (which should be scanning continuously) but saves power on your mobile device

Comment: Actually I need to check the presence only few times per day. So it should not be that bad with advertising. 95% of time esp32 would be off.

Comment: You could start simulating a peripheral on your android device using an app such as _BLE Peripheral Simulator_ or _nRF Connect_

Comment: but this would drain my battery which is the think I'm trying to avoid

Comment: This will not drain your battery as much as you think. BLE is pretty power saving already. You will need to write your own application later, which would allow you to control the advertising interval to reduce power consumption even more. But for testing this would be more then suitable

Comment: i have idea to advert esp32 as joystick or mouse. android will autoconnect to it.